# Expanded Tree Cache Full Exception while executing XQuery on a huge number of documents

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to retrieve value of XPath from multiple documents. In my case approximately 800k documents. I am getting and exception called

> Expanded Tree cache full.

The same query yields the expected output when there are less documents i.e for 400k documents.

Following is the query used to retrieve value of XPath from collections: *collection1* and *collection2*:

```
cts:search(doc(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:collection-query("collection1"), 
    cts:collection-query("collection2")
  ))
)/xpath/text()
```

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. People aren't going to know what are "lakh documents"

Comment: You could also add indexes for your elements, and do an element value query instead of Xpathing all the docs.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why you are pulling up those values? Are you looking for a list of values? Or do you need to process/update those documents?

Answer (score 5):

Each document you return from a query must be loaded into memory in full - that is the expanded tree cache. Therefore, a single query is limited by the number of documents it can fit into memory.

For queries that need to read the entire database - or a large subset - you should implement paging or batching to prevent the error. If you are trying to export documents from the database [MLCP](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) will do the batching for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Please see if the answer here will help you: https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/9/16/resolving-xdmp-expntreecachefull-errors.

> When the query needs to actually retrieve elements, values, or otherwise traverse the contents of one of these fragments, the fragment is uncompressed and cached in the expanded tree cache.

So, try rewriting the query to retrieve less number of documents. If you have enough memory, increasing expanded tree cache size may help you also.